MaxMind GeoLite Configuration with MMDB_ADDR
Has anyone had success with the MaxMind GeoIP/GeoLite configuration where you specify the IP address by setting the environment variable MMDB_ADDR?
I'm wondering if it needs to go in a specific place in the apache configuration.  The only way I have been able to set it is via SetEnvIf.  But it doesn't actually work as the documentation states.
This does not work:
MaxMindDBEnable On
SetEnv MMDB_ADDR 192.168.1.300
MaxMindDBFile DB /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE ^(RU|DE|FR) BlockCountry
Deny from env=BlockCountry

